# store strings in db with asymmetric encryption for a python app keeping the data secure

Tags: encryption, authentication, account-security, mysql, python

I'm designing an app that receives sensitive data input from a user and that data needs to be saved securely in a database.
As far as I understand it needs asymmetric encryption but since this app has a login to authenticate. I need this previously saved data to be read again by the user without serious security problems and I need the keys not to be saved locally. I don't know how to do it because it's my first project that requires these specifications. I was thinking of creating a strong authentication, perhaps using an otp.

Comment: Welcome to the community. I think using a decent cloud provider's key vault or whatever it's called service is what you're looking for. I apparently cannot specifically name the service names...

Comment: "As far as I understand it needs asymmetric encryption" why do you think that's the case?

Comment: Idk, i need the most secure way to store this sensitive data, maybe asimmetrical encryption its right. I have another question, is it possible to do reverse engineering and catching the database s credentials using the function mysql.connector.connect()?

Comment: the reason for using asymmetric encryption is so you can hold the public keys (the means to encrypt) on the internet-facing server, without holding the private keys (the means to decrypt) - however, this implies a one-way op ; if you need the user to be able to view and revise prior input, then you need the private and public (or shared, symmetric) keys at some point during processing - this depends entirely on your app requirements ; if your db creds are on the compromised server then you don't need to rev-engineer anything, simply read creds from the same source as the authorised software